# Vintageous plugin for Sublime 3 resets INSERT MODE to COMMAND MODE on alt+tab

Tags: sublimetext3

[Vintageous plugin](https://github.com/guillermooo/Vintageous) for Sublime 3 resets INSERT MODE to COMMAND MODE on alt+tab. How to circumvent this?

**Detailed description**

1. Enter edit mode (status bar shows INSERT)
2. Press Alt+Tab and return to sublime window
3. Editor has exited the INSERT mode (status does not contain INSERT)

**Versions**

Latest sublime build 3059, Vintageous plugin 3.0.1 on ubuntu 13.10

Answer (score 2):

Add this line to your user settings:

```
"vintageous_reset_mode_when_switching_tabs": false
```